# Ajax Parsing XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, xml

I have a `loginmein.aspx` page with two textboxes and a button. I am calling a web service called `verify.aspx`, that if the login is correct, it returns *hello!* in xml format(below).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<response>
    <command method="alert">
        <message>hello world!</message>
    </command>
</response>
```

I have built another simple application to learn how to call the same web service via ajax.

How do I read "hello !" and display true or false by ajax to a label on a browser?

Comment: How are you going to determine the `true` or `false` from this 'hello world' response?

Comment: if it reads hello world! in the xml, that means it is successful, true, if it doesn't read hello world ! false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the XML response using `DOMParser`:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        var resXml = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = resXml;

        var parser = new DOMParser(),
            doc = parser.parseFromString(resXml, 'text/xml'),
            message = doc.querySelector('response > command > message');

        // check for existence of 'message' element
        if (message != null)
            alert(message.textContent); // hello world!
        else
            alert('Oops!'); // error
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "microsoft/webservice/verify.aspx?username= " + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

See [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: Haim770 thank you for taking the time to answer the question, how would I link my web service URL with this function ?

Comment: Have you managed to issue an Ajax request to the web-service endpoint and getting a response?

Comment: I have gotten a response through success or fail (1 Or 0) of login but the DomParser, how do I use my web service url with DomParser ?

Comment: var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://microsoft/webservice/verify.aspx?username= " + document.getElementById("txtUserName").value + "&password=" + document.getElementById("txtPassword").value, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
         
        }

Comment: Thank you gain ! i want to throw a curve ball at you , what happens if the html input textboxes have no Id and uses the same class name ?

Comment: Then `getElementById` will return null and you'll get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

Comment: It begins with getting the webservice first, but after  the process never gets past if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200.

Comment: Check your console for errors. Maybe you're performing a cross-domain request that is denied.

Comment: No errors in the firebug tool. Cross domain request ? What's that?

Comment: If `xmlhttp.status` is not `200` then what is the status?

Comment: 12007 is the xmlhttp status